# How do I take a credit card subscription in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've been looking for a way to add a monthly subscription with free trial to my product.  I've noticed some apps, like Life360 (screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lns3.png)), do this through credit card billing rather than an iTunes account.  I've searched all through the developer documentation and cannot find an API to allow a user to enter a credit card outside their iTunes account.

Is there an API for this?

[image]

Comment: Doesnt in app purchasing allow for monthly subscriptions now?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through Apple for all credit card transactions if you want to be accepted in the App Store.

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies), 11.2:

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

And 11.3:

> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used
>   outside of the App will be rejected

So, yes, so-and-so does it, but you aren't so-and-so, so you probably will be rejected for doing it.

Comment: That's what I thought, but then how does Life 360 do it?

Comment: Not *entirely* true - you can buy stuff from Amazon.com via their app w/o IAP.

Comment: This is not true. You can use Stripe for instance.

Comment: You can, but Apple will reject it.

Comment: For a subscription, most likely. But selling other goods they will not.

Comment: @woz I believe Apple treats physical merchandise differently, which is probably how Amazon gets through. I know they didn't have enough power to get an exception for the Kindle app.

Comment: This isn't true. Many companies use Stripe for purchases like Uber and others to do in app purchases that do not require a physical product.

Comment: @Bot I'd consider an Uber ride to be a "physical product" - it's a car ride. I'm talking about stuff like e-books, cash for your Farmville farm, etc.

Comment: @Bot It says "using IAP...".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in API for this. You need to use a third party like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). However by having a subscription system that does not go through the appstore you will likely be rejected.

Most apps that use content (news, magazines) will need to use in app purchases. Apps that provide a service such as insurance etc can usually be added by working with someone from Apple in order to get it into the app store such as Uber.

Answer (score 1):

Apple frowns on this, in general, for non-physical merchandise. Chances are good your app will be rejected (and Life 360 might have just slipped through - it happens!)

There's definitely not a credit card API built into iOS. You'd need to use a third-party for your payment processing. Stripe is a popular one, and has a page on iOS integration: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios